# Truncating Numbers with Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, casting, numbers, oracle12c

This is not about truncating to decimal places. Rather, truncating whole numbers with Oracle 12c.

```
select CAST('123456789' AS NUMBER(4)) from DUAL;
```

It would be great if this returned '1234' instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Why would that be a "simple request"?  That's not a result that is obviously sensible.  The number 12346789 is 10,000 times larger than 1234.  Why would it make sense to return this rather than throwing an error?  You could, of course, use `substr` to pick off the first 4 digits of your string and then cast that to a number.  You'd need to implement that logic because that's a very business requirement-specific behavior.

Comment: I concur with Justin's Statement.  For what you are trying to do you need to treat it like a string...  `Select CAST('123456789' AS VARCHAR(4)) from DUAL;`

Comment: SQL Server does it with CONVERT(). It's one call. Apparently Oracle doesn't compete in this way! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Justin, it is not sensible to do so. But it can be done like this.

```
select cast(substr('123456789',1,4) as integer) from dual;
```

But this will not work in following scenarios.

1. You have `0` before the number.
2. You have a decimal digit before
   4th digit `(ex 123.4)`